# Cannot Delete the Workrole

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Im trying to delete that specific workrole followed by id. Im using postman to delete this thing but i can't i cannot figured out what the mistake i written the code exactly it shown in video but i cant delete my workrole
Before this workrole i also performed user deleting process it works perfect but in this process i don't know what's wrong with this function
here is the code behind deleting the workrole

### Plz help me.....

```
// @type    DELETE
// @route   /api/profile/workrole/:w_id
// @desc    route for delete specific work profile of a person
// @access  PRIVATE

router.delete('/workrole/:w_id'), passport.authenticate('jwt' , {session: false}), (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
        .then(profile => {
            //assignment to check if we got a profile
            const removeThis = profile.workrole
                .map(item => item.id)
                .indexOf(req.params.w_id);

            profile.workrole.splice(removeThis, 1);

            profile.save()
                .then(profile => {
                    res.json(profile)
                })
                .catch(err => console.log('Error on saving workrole after removing ' + err));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error in deleting workrole ' + err));
}

module.exports = router;
```

## Here is the error message shown in postman

```
Cannot DELETE /api/profile/workrole/5d10cbba5fb5b11ab0cd3bdb
```

### In console there is no error message shown

Comment: I would guess that DELETE is not a supported method

Comment: The following application i also performed user delete its works perfect @frobinsonj

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure maybe this error is coming from the constant variable i used (removeThis) after changing this constant variable into (removeWorkrole) it worked. Here is final code...

```
router.delete('/workrole/:w_id', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res)=> {
    Profile.findOne({user: req.user.id})
        .then(profile => {
            // assignment to check if we got a profile
            const removeWorkrole = profile.workrole.map(item => item.id).indexOf(req.params.w_id);

            profile.workrole.splice(removeWorkrole, 1);
            profile.save()
                .then(profile => res.json(profile))
                .catch(err => console.log('Error on saving workrole: ' + err));
        })
        .catch(err => console.log("Error on finding the user: " + err));
});
```